# Split a large table to some tables and cross table query

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition, that holds a single database, 
which itself has almost nothing except a large table(blog table)。
The table is 100+ million rows (35 columns) and growing at around 200,000 rows per day. We need all the data to be "online",
and most of the columns need to be searchable in some fashion.

I would like to split the table to some small tables by month. Example:

```
table1  :1/1/2013-1/31/2013
table2  :2/1/2013-2/28/2013
table3  :3/1/2013-3/31/2013
table4  :4/1/2013-4/29/2013
.....
table12 :12/1/2013-12/31/2013
```

Assume that a user post some blog entries at 2 month(1 blog entry),4 month(2 blog entries ), 10 month(5 blog entries) 
, 11 month(no blog entry) and 12 month(no blog entry)

There is a requirement:

Assume that current date is 12/20/2013.In order to get the recently 10 blog entries about this user,I have to union all 12 tables

I think this design is inefficiency.if so? How to design ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rather have a look at using [Partitioned Table and Index Concepts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Partitioning makes large tables or indexes more manageable, because
>   partitioning enables you to manage and access subsets of data quickly
>   and efficiently, while maintaining the integrity of a data collection.

SQL Server has this functionality built in for you, so dont try to manage this on your own.

Also look at [Designing Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175533%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Please take not that

> Partitioned tables and indexes are available only on the Enterprise,
>   Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server.

But in your case that would be fine.

Comment: @user441222,no you don't have use union all for all 12 twelve.
just normal select will do.though i am not sure.Be sure to keep back up before doing partition